# Searching fast in big binary file in python

Tags: python, performance, data-structures

I have list of ~6000 data patterns for which I need to search in a relatively large (100 MB) binary file, so in worst case I need to traverse this binary file 6000 times.

Is there any way or any property of python data structure that I can use for fast search within a large binary file?

Comment: Multiprocess. If you're performing read-only operations, there's no reason this isn't safe.

Comment: yes I am performing read only operation. Any other idea ?

Comment: Also, can you define "data pattern"? I've never heard this term.

Comment: here data pattern means simple stream of bytes, I will update question